# Polymorphic include on ActiveRecord classname issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having an issue where the classname stored on a polymorphic relationship is flip flopping in whether it uses the full namespaced name or not.  I am trying to get is_taggable is work with my current application (https://github.com/ejlevin1/is_taggable); however, as shown below, it isn't always obeying the `ActiveRecord::Base.store_full_sti_class = false`.

Here is my example:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > i = BOSS::Model::Interest.includes(:taggings).first
 ... 
Tagging Load (40.7ms)  SELECT [taggings].* FROM [taggings] WHERE ([taggings].[taggable_id] = 1 and [taggings].[taggable_type] = 'Interest')
 ...
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > BOSS::Model::Interest.first.taggings
 ...
Tagging Load (43.8ms)  SELECT [taggings].* FROM [taggings] WHERE ([taggings].taggable_id = 1 AND [taggings].taggable_type = N'BOSS::Model::Interest')
```

Notice how the taggable types are different based on the way I access the `has_many :taggings` association on my object?

You can see the appropriate classes here: https://github.com/ejlevin1/is_taggable/tree/master/lib

All I am doing within my application is attaching this to a model class by specifying:

```
module BOSS
  module Model
    class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
      is_taggable :category
    end
  end
end
```

anyone have any recommendations or thoughts??

Comment: This gem looks pretty old.  Last commit to the code base was August 2009.  Might not be compatible with modern versions of ActiveRecord.  Also, just out of curiosity, what is the purpose of burying your model inside of module's like you're doing here?

Comment: Yea, I noticed that the gem was old... We namespaced the models because they are packaged in a gem and didn't want to introduce conflicts with other gems and such.  I upgraded the named_scopes in hopes that would help here: https://github.com/ejlevin1/is_taggable/blob/master/lib/tag.rb but still no luck?